# Given a name, return a string with the message: One for X, one for me.Where X is the given name.I wote code and got error while not passing any arg

Tags: python, string

> Given a name, return a string with the message:
>
> One for X, one for me.
>
> Where X is the given name.
>
> However, if the name is missing, return the string:

> One for you, one for me.

Here are some examples:

```
Name    String to return
Alice   One for Alice, one for me.
Bob     One for Bob, one for me.
    One for you, one for me.
Zaphod  One for Zaphod, one for me.
Exception messages --> and when missing name, func  should return: "One for you, one for me."
```

```
def two_fer(name):
    if name=="":
        print("One for you, one for me.")
    else:
        print("One for {}, one for me.".format(name))
```

Comment: The instructions say to *return* a string, not *print* a string.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1):

You just make name variable optional like this

```
def two_fer(name = ""):   # replace this line
    if name=="":
        print("One for you, one for me.")
    else:
        print("One for {}, one for me.".format(name))

two_fer()
```

now the output will be
"One for you, one for me."